# JavaFX - Using "-fx-background-radius" in CSS makes my app way slower

Tags: ios, css, performance, javafx, javafxports

So here is the case. I am implementing an application using JavaFXPorts and I would like to create a ToggleButton with rounded shapes. This button is then placed on a GridPane, which holds also an HBox wrapped in a ScrollPane. To keep this simple I am just giving the tree with the nodes that GridPane holds.

```
GridPane
|___________ ToggleButton
|___________ ScrollPane
             |__________ HBox
                         |_______ 20+ Images here
```

So, when I compile this on iPhone 5 everything runs smoothly and great. I can scroll horizontally the HBox and see the images in it.

However, when I use the CSS code below things start to change. The performance of scrolling degrades to the point where it gets laggy. After playing with the styles I have noticed that the problem is cause of the **"-fx-(backgroud/border)-radius"** styles. I think that this is possible a bug. I have tried also to **cache** the nodes, whcih gives some speed improvement but it's still laggy.

Note that running the same app on iPhone 6, it performs OK.

```
.rounded_button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-border-color: lightgray;
    -fx-font-size: 0.9em;
    -fx-pref-height: 33px;
    -fx-background-radius: 0em 1.5em 1.5em 0em; 
    -fx-border-radius: 0 1.5em 1.5em 0;
}
```

I have also enabled pulse logger, and here is the output:

```
PULSE: 556 [73887ms:327ms]
T1 (-73886 +73887ms): Layout Pass
T1 (0 +14ms): CSS Pass
T1 (14 +2ms): Layout Pass
T1 (16 +0ms): Update bounds
T1 (17 +0ms): Waiting for previous rendering
T1 (17 +0ms): Copy state to render graph
T7 (18 +0ms): Dirty Opts Computed
T7 : 2 different dirty regions to render
T7 : Dirty Region 0: RectBounds { minX:183.0, minY:157.0, maxX:219.0, maxY:180.0} (w:36.0, h:23.0)
T7 : Render Root Path 0: [com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@578c420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@56314d0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@5631420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4d03420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@adca630, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4d03160, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4d030b0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@49294d0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@49296e0]
T7 : Dirty Region 1: RectBounds { minX:310.0, minY:63.0, maxX:319.0, maxY:519.0} (w:9.0, h:456.0)
T7 : Render Root Path 1: [com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@578c420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@56314d0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@5631420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4d03420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@adca630, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4d03160]
T7 (18 +0ms): Render Roots Discovered
T7 : Slow background path for null
T7 : Slow shape path for null
T7 : Slow background path for null
T7 : Slow shape path for null
T7 : Slow background path for null
T7 (18 +305ms): Painting
T7 (324 +0ms): Painting
T7 (325 +2ms): Presenting
Counters:
    CacheFilter rebuilding: 3
    NGRegion renderBackgroundShape slow path: 2
    NGRegion renderBackgrounds slow path: 3
    Nodes rendered: 57
    Nodes visited during render: 71
```

Without **-fx-background-radius**, **-fx-border-radius**:

```
PULSE: 1493 [89717ms:37ms]
T1 (-89717 +89717ms): Layout Pass
T1 (0 +13ms): CSS Pass
T1 (13 +1ms): Layout Pass
T1 (15 +0ms): Update bounds
T1 (16 +0ms): Waiting for previous rendering
T1 (16 +0ms): Copy state to render graph
T7 (16 +0ms): Dirty Opts Computed
T7 : 2 different dirty regions to render
T7 : Dirty Region 0: RectBounds { minX:183.0, minY:157.0, maxX:219.0, maxY:180.0} (w:36.0, h:23.0)
T7 : Render Root Path 0: [com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@542b420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@578a370, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@578a2c0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@556e840, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@556e0b0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@556e420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@556e370, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4c9f580, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4c9f630, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4c9f790, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@4c9f8f0]
T7 : Dirty Region 1: RectBounds { minX:310.0, minY:63.0, maxX:319.0, maxY:519.0} (w:9.0, h:456.0)
T7 : Render Root Path 1: [com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@542b420, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@578a370, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@578a2c0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@556e840, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@556e0b0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@556e420]
T7 (16 +0ms): Render Roots Discovered
T7 : Slow background path for null
T7 : Slow shape path for null
T7 : Slow background path for null
T7 : Slow shape path for null
T7 (17 +17ms): Painting
T7 (35 +0ms): Painting
T7 (35 +1ms): Presenting
Counters:
    CacheFilter rebuilding: 3
    NGRegion renderBackgroundShape slow path: 2
    NGRegion renderBackgrounds slow path: 2
    Nodes rendered: 57
    Nodes visited during render: 71
```

Pulse completes in **37ms** without the styles.

Thank you in advance

### Update

You can download Source Code from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqtf12mcyhata3g/javasunsFX.zip?dl=0).

Below is a screenshot from iPhone 5. When scrolling horizontaly the HBox that contains buttons ABC, BCD, CDE, etc, that's when things start to get laggy. On the bottom right image, is a screenshot after I deleted the .css style, and scrolling works fine.

[image][image]

### Update

[Video Without CSS](https://youtu.be/kpGnx3tVOhk)

[Video With CSS](https://youtu.be/EO0p7OgHqFo)

Comment: Thanks for reporting, we have created an internal issue. It will help us if you can share a Gist/Pastebin with a minimal sample that reproduces it (code, build.gradle and output). Thank you

Comment: @JoséPereda I have updated now my thread, including a link with the files. The example, is the one where the horizontal scrolling is slow when -fx-background-radius is on. You will also notice that this FXML takes sometime to load. I think comboboxes are also one of the reason of this result. Thank you

Comment: @JoséPereda Any news on this laggy issues?

Comment: I checked your code, and I could notice some slightly slower response when css was present, but nothing conclusive yet.

Comment: @JoséPereda I have uploaded two video at the end of this post to see that the response is way slower.

Comment: @javasuns Any news/updates?